# Time series export from ArcGIS Desktop to KML not working in Google Earth?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, google-earth, time, encoding

I am having trouble with the KML export. My time series will not work properly in google earth, it has time start in 0001 when it should start in the year 2001.

My incidents time is coded `YYYYMMDDHHSS` do you think if I cut it back to `YYYYMMDD` that it would work?

It is a geocoded series of terrorist attacks in Afghanistan.

Works fine in arcmap 10 and arcglobe 10.

Comment: I would start with examining the kml, and in editing the KML you can also experiment and see what works. I would also try to simplify and isolate the problem there.

Answer (score 2):

Here here is my proposal:

- **TimeStamp** and **TimeSpan** elements are actually defined in the OGC KML version 2.2 [XSD](http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd), hopefully a glimpse at it helps you to devise a quick fix or
- pick up a good **XML validation** tools and probe your KML files against (Google extensions to OGC) KML's [XSD](https://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd).